# How to get the list values from another class in Java

Tags: java

How can I access list of one class in another class using Java.
I'm getting an empty list by using the following code.

My code :

```
public class DataRead {

  public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

  public void readData() {

    list.add("abc");
    list.add("xyz");
  }
}

public class GetListData {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> getList = DataRead.list;
    System.out.println(getList); //getting null
  }
}
```

My edited code:

```
public class GetListData {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DataRead dataRead = new DataRead();
        dataRead.readData();  //Add elements to list
        List<String> myList = DataRead.list;       
        System.out.println(myList.get(0)); 
    }
}
```

Still getting empty set after editing the code.

Comment: The list is null since nothing is inside it yet. The readData method hasn't been called on it.

Comment: @NiallMitch14 `null` and empty are not the same thing.

Comment: I'm getting empty list.I'm trying to get the list values in "GetListData" class.Can u please edit the code

Comment: Is there a reason you're accessing `list` in a static way instead of using a get method?

Comment: I had edited the code.Can anyone please review and help me out ...

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually call `readData()` method first, which fills your `List`, e.g.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DataRead().readData();
    List<String> getList = DataRead.list;
    System.out.println(getList);
  }
```

After OP's edit:
I doubt you're getting an empty result - [check it out on ideone](http://ideone.com/Pj3Ewn).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, the list is still empty. To read from the list, you need to get specific element out from it:

```
list.get(x);  //where x is an int value
```

The reason the list has no elements added is because the statements for adding into the list resides in `readData` method. You need to invoke the method first:

```
DataRead dataRead = new DataRead();
dataRead.readData();
```

So to read the elements, you can go with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    DataRead dataRead = new DataRead();
    dataRead.readData();  //Add elements to list
    List<String> myList = DataRead.list;       
    System.out.println(myList.get(0)); //getting "abc"
}
```

If list is not meant to be shared, but as a property of individual DataRead object, I would do it as:

```
class DataRead
{
    //Your other attributes..
    private List<String> list;

    public DataRead(){
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    public <ArrayList> getList(){
        return list;
    }
    public void addToList(String s){
        list.add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you actually need to call `readData` as there is no constructor shown

Comment: @Ascalonian Gosh, I overlooked it. I thought is was a contructor...the naming he uses..geez. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this.

```
public class DataRead {
  public List<String> list;

  public void DataRead() {
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("abc");
    list.add("xyz");
  }
}
```

And use it as follows.

```
public class GetListData {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DataRead d = new DataRead();
    List<String> getList = d.list;
    System.out.println(getList); //getting null
  }
}
```

The best approach would be to use Getters and setters and do not make the variables static, unless and until its required.

Comment: You probably wanted to create a `DataRead` constructor, right? Currently, you created a `void` method instead...